# array of char pointer segfaulting

Tags: c++

The code below works fine if factors is small but when it gets larger I get a segmentation fault.The first instance I have encountered is at a size of ~800.000.
This should easily fit into memory or what am I missing?
Appreciate any help.

```
char  *fgs_arr [facs().size()],  
      *true_arr[facs().size()],  
      *maps_arr[facs().size()];
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something: `facs().size()` doesn't look like a valid C syntax to me.

Comment: You might want to provide more information about what environment you are developing in.

Comment: Are you sure the segfault occurs here and not somewhere else?

Comment: @AleksG It's probably another language, but even in C, if `facs` return struct that has member `int (*size)()`, it's valid.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose it is :)

Comment: Sorry, actually it's C/C++ facs() returns a std::vector so this is not the issue. And I am pretty sure it's here

Comment: @user1214505: please don't mix the languages.  That's like saying you have a question with the German/English language.  They're completely different except in a few minor ways.

Comment: It isn't valid C++ syntax either. C++ doesn't allow for variable-sized arrays. Maybe it's g++ or MSVC++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running out of Stack (The place where locally declared memory goes). You'll either need to dynamically declare it (this goes to the heap which is much larger) or increase stack size.

Comment: I believe _dynamically_ declared memory goes on the stack.

Comment: nope. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap

Comment: Thanks, actually what I needed was: char **fgs_arr = new char*[facs().size()]

Answer (score 3):

Since vla is on the stack, and the stack is (in most case) 1MB, it should **not** easily fit into memory. Use malloc instead (and don't forget to free).

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, you are running out of stack space. Switching to `new` is inelegant; it promotes memory leaks and other bugs. Try `std::vector<char*>`:

```
std::vector<char*> fgs_arr(facs().size());
std::vector<char*> true_arr(facs().size());
std::vector<char*> maps_arr(facs().size());
```